# Find selenium Xpath to click on "My Account"

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

How do i find Xpath to click on "My Account" menu on following website  "https://www.phptravels.net/"
it does not allow compound class name and i have tried with href and link text but it does not work. Help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: *What* does not allow compound class name? and what did you try that didn't work?

Comment: **//nav[contains(@class,'navbar-default')]//a[contains(text(),'My Account')] ** use this, as the page has two My Account elements. one on default view and other on side bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this xpath :

```
//nav[contains(@class,'navbar-default')]//li[@id='li_myaccount']//a[contains(@class,'dropdown-toggle')]
```

CSS selector:
 `nav.navbar-default li#li_myaccount a.dropdown-toggle`

I have tried these and they are working.

Comment: It works Thank you. But what was your logic or how you decided to use this kind of Xpath ?

Comment: As the MyAccount was present on nav bar so i followed it from nav bar and made this selector. Many other elements are also present with "MyAccount" as text but it differs from them as it will give only that button that is present on navigation bar. If that solved your problem can you please mark it as an answer:)

Comment: Thank you, but i didn't get that why you skipped all the "div" tags?

Comment: you just navigate to the unique specific tags and no need to use the divs or elements coming in path.